# Translate state names

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have states in 2 languages, like this:

```
$stateProvider
.state('contacts', {
    url: "/contacts",
    templateUrl: 'contacts.html'
});

$stateProvider
.state('contacts.edit', {
    url: "/edit",
    templateUrl: 'contacts.html'
})

$stateProvider
.state('contatos', {
    url: "/contatos",
    templateUrl: 'contacts.html'
})

$stateProvider
.state('contatos.editar', {
    url: "/editar",
    templateUrl: 'contacts.html'
})
```

Right now I'm looping an array to push all my states.

Is there another way to do that?

Comment: ...well, maybe, you can optimize the creation, but at the end you have to have all the states doubled... if they must have different url. But would you really profit from localized url? won't it be in fact disadvantage... almost like having two domains... Just a suggestion: I would avoid this approach, rather localize the page content than url...

Comment: Sure, my page will be also localized.
I'm doing this for SEO and [DWIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM) purposes.

I want my users to able to deduce the next URL if they try to. Since is a localized page, it makes sense that a user from Brazil write "editar" rather than "edit".

Comment: I do understand what you are trying to achieve... but imagine that someone wants to send a link to other.. both in different languages.. the url in this case should be "general" ... I would say ... but just a suggestion

Comment: Not really.
If someone wants to send a link to others, both `site.com/edit` and `site.com/editar` will work.

Comment: I am saying that this `site.com/pohovky/upravit/` *(localized to Czech)* will not make sense to not Czech speaking... localizing url simply does not make sense *(only developers do read them;)*... Maybe, remember me later ;)

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Your state name isn't used for what the user does, so that doesn't need to be translated. Only the URL does. Unfortunately ui-router doesn't yet support having multiple URLs in a single state, but somebody has a solution using urlMatcherFactory decoration here:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/185#issuecomment-48124930

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look!

I had to translate the state name, otherwise UI Router won't understand child states.

Comment: Only because you are currently having to add the separate entries for each URL. If you can localize the URLs, you can collapse the states that use them and you'll be home-free!